# MYSQL drop duplicates of userid

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I thought I'd made the column `userid` in my table `"userslive"` unique, but somehow must have made a mistake. I've seen multiple answers to this question, but I'm afraid of messing up again so I hope someone can help me directly.

So this table has no unique columns, but I've got a column "timer" which was the timestamp of scraping the data. If possible I'd like to drop rows with the lowest `"timer"` with duplicate `"userid"` column.

It's a fairly big table at about `2 million` rows (`20 columns`). There is about `1000` duplicate `userid` which I've found using this query:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) as cnt FROM userslive GROUP BY userid HAVING (cnt > 1);
```

Is this the correct syntax? I tried this on a backup table, but I suspect this is too heavy for a table this big (unless left to run for a very long time.

```
  DELETE FROM userslive using userslive,
      userslive e1
  where userslive.timer < e1.timer
      and userslive.userid = e1.userid
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

EDIT: I should say the "timer" is not a unique column.

Comment: You can test what your `delete` is going to delete by doing the same query but with `select`. You should also do this inside a transaction so you can roll back if you make a mistake. Finally, what version of MySQL?

Comment: Hey, version 8.0.20. Thanks for the other tips :)

Comment: *... I'm afraid of messing up again so ...* What prevents you from trying solutions on a copy of the table? *Is this the correct syntax?* No.

Comment: I'm trying a bunch of solutions on a copy of the table, its just hard to veryfy how successful it was. I could check there are no more duplicates, but maybe I deleted more, or somehow messed something else up. I'm sorry if my question bothers you.

Comment: *I'm trying a bunch of solutions on a copy of the table, its just hard to veryfy how successful it was.* ?? What prevents to create sample/test table with 10-15 records, some with 2 or even 3 copies, some unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t1.*     /* delete from a copy named t1 only */
FROM userslive t1, userslive t2
WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid  
  AND t1.timer < t2.timer
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02785777217db786dfd4599ead578ba3)

Logic: if for some record (in a copy aliased as t1) we can find a record (in a table copy aliased as t2) with the same user but with greater/later timer value - this record must be deleted.

Comment: @Mixy Fiddle added - ensure.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past and the easiest way to solve this is to add an id column and then select userid, max(new_id) into a new table and join that for the delete. Something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE `userslive` 
    ADD `new_id` INT  UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY;
```

Now you have your new unique column and create a new table for selecting the ones to delete.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_to_delete` 
AS 
SELECT userid, new_id 
FROM (
    SELECT userid, max(new_id) new_id, count(*) user_rows
    FROM `userslive`
    GROUP BY 1
) dataset 
WHERE user_rows > 1
```

Then use that to delete your duplicate rows by joining it into a DELETE statement like this:

```
DELETE `userslive` FROM `userslive` 
    INNER JOIN `users_to_delete` USING(userid,new_id);
```

Make sure you back everything up before you delete anything just in case.

Comment: Got a syntax error on "rows", maybe this has been deprecated in version 8.0.20? I should have specified in the OP. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Mixy *Got a syntax error on "rows", maybe this has been deprecated in version 8.0.20?* No - this is an effect of using reserved word as a name/alias.

Comment: ok, that's my bad. change rows to user_rows and you'll be good to go.